# Call function to post to server and perform task based on response

Tags: php, android, multithreading, post

I am working on android/php project. I am making a library for android that the user calls an initialisation function and I pass the function an ID.

The function should then do an HTTP post to my server where it checks my database that the ID exists. Based on the response from the server, I need to set to either set that initialisation is completed or else log an error to say that initialisation couldn't be completed.

However, because I need to run the post in a thread my code drops straight down to the next line of code which means initialisation has failed. So how can I pause the code execution until the thread has completed.

Below is the initilisation function.

```
public static void Initialise(Context context, String appID)
    {
        appContext = context;
        CritiMon.appID = appID;
        isAppIdCorrect(appID);
        if (appIdValid)
        {
            isInitialised = true;
        }
        else
        {
            Log.e("CritiMon Initialisation", "Incorrect App ID was detected. Please check that you have entered the correct app ID. The app ID can be found on the web pages");
        }
    }
```

Below is the `isAppIdCorrect` function

```
private static void isAppIdCorrect(String appID)
    {

        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                try
                {
                    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(appContext.getString(R.string.post_url) + "/AccountManagement.php");

                    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("type", "checkAppId"));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("appID", CritiMon.appID));

                    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                    InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();
                    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
                    ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(20);

                    int current = 0;
                    while ((current = bis.read()) != -1)
                    {
                        baf.append((byte)current);
                    }

                    Log.d("Http Response", new String(baf.toByteArray()));

                    String httpResponse = new String(baf.toByteArray());

                    if (httpResponse.equals("200 OK"))
                    {
                        appIdValid = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        appIdValid = false;
                    }

                }
                catch (ClientProtocolException ex)
                {
                    Log.e("ClientProtocolException", ex.toString());
                }
                catch (IOException ex)
                {
                    Log.e("IOException", ex.toString());
                }
                appIdCheckComplete = true;
            }
        }).start();
    }
```

So in the above code, the `isAppIdCorrect` function is returning `200 OK` as expected, but because that function is in a thread, it immediatly goes to the if statement before the thread completed, so the if statement is false, and therefore says initialisation has failed.

How can I wait for the thread to complete so I can check the variable.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use async model with starting thread and setting some kind of onCompleteListener and do nothing before it fires. Take a look at [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) class.